# Choice of generators to make the centralisers connected

Tags: finite-groups, lie-groups, connectedness, involutions, classical-groups

In $G=\operatorname{PGL}_{2n}(\textbf{C})$, WLG, we assume all the toral elementary abelian 2-subgroups in discussion are in $T$, the image in $G$ of the group of diagonal matrices in $\operatorname{GL}_{2n}(\textbf{C})$.

I'm aware that the conjugacy classes of involutions in $G$ have representatives $$a_{j}=\left[ \begin{pmatrix}
-I_{j} & 0 \\
0 & I_{2n-j} 
\end{pmatrix} \right]$$ where $j=1..n$ and $C_{G}(a_{j})=C_{G}(a_{j})^{\circ}$ for $j=1..n-1$ and $C_{G}(a_{n})=\langle C_{G}(a_{n})^{\circ},b_{n}\rangle$ where $b_{n}$ is an order 2 element. At last, $C_{G}(\langle e_{1},e_{2}\rangle)^{\circ} = C_{G}(e_{1})^{\circ}\cap C_{G}(e_{2})^{\circ}$ for any two involutions.

As a result, for an elementary abelian 2-subgroup $E$, we have $C_{G}(E)=C_{G}(E)^{\circ}$ when none of the generators of $E$ is conjugate to $a_{n}$. If there is one generator of $E$ conjugate to $a_{n}$, after we identify this generator with $a_{n}$, we see if the $b_{n}$ associated with $a_{n}$ centralizes all the other generators, then $C_{G}(E) \neq C_{G}(E)^{\circ}.$

I hope to show for an elementary abelian 2-subgroup $E$, we have $C_{G}(E)=C_{G}(E)^{\circ}$ if and only if there is a choice of generators of $E$ s.t. none of them is conjugate to $a_{n}$.

The right implying the left is clear. For the other direction, I'm thinking to show if there is one generator conjugate to $a_{n}$, we can replace it with an element not conjugate to $a_{n}$, using the connectedness of the centralizer somehow. So far this has led me nowhere.. Any help would be appreciated.